# Getting "attempt power cycle", "USB disconnect, device number 2" and similar errors only on Linux Debian, not on Windows or BIOS

Tags: debian, usb, usb-device

I have a desktop computer with an AMD FX 8350 CPU, an Asus M5A99X EVO R2.0 motherboard, 32 GB RAM and an EVGA 850 W Bronze PSU. I dual boot Debian 12 Bookworm and Windows 10 Professional on it. Recently, my motherboard's USB 1.0, 2.0 and front 3.0 ports began failing under Linux, getting the error messages posted below on `dmesg -w` every time I attempt to connect something on the USB 2.0 ports.

What sets apart this instance of not detecting USB devices from the no less than 20 instances of this issue I have read on Google, is that it only seems to happen on Linux; on Windows 10, GRUB, and on UEFI BIOS, all these USB ports seem to work just fine. I can literally enter BIOS setup with my keyboard plugged on an USB 2.0 port, tinker with BIOS setup, choose to boot from the drive where I have GRUB, move through the GRUB menu with my keyboard on one of the motherboard's USB 2.0 ports, and then, once the Linux kernel takes over, it stops working.

Here is a list of things I have tried in vain to fix this problem:

- Turning off the computer, unplugging the PSU from mains, pressing the power button to drain the PSU and motherboard's capacitors, plugging it back and starting. Didn't work.
- Checking if my motherboard has some kind of USB port gimmick like Always-On or USB Charge or whatever. I didn't see it on the BIOS configuration, but I did see it on the Windows tool that has access to it, disabled it and rebooted back to Linux. Didn't work.
- Unplugging and plugging miscellaneous devices. Didn't work.
- Reloading modules ohci_pci, ohci_hcd, ehci_pci and ehci_hcd. Didn't work.
- Going to directory `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci-pci`, taking note of all the devices listed such as `0000:00:12.0`, and rebinding each device with `for X in "0000:00:12.0" "0000:00:13.0" ...; do echo "$X" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci-pci/unbind; echo "$X" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ohci-pci/bind; done`. Didn't work.
- Reinstalling Linux kernel and all packages in my system that had the word "firmware" in it. TBE.

---

Exhibit A, from starting with keyboard and mouse plugged on USB 2.0 on a cold boot:

```
[   35.759939] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ohci-pci
[   35.919935] usb 10-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   36.191935] usb 10-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   36.455931] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ohci-pci
[   36.615932] usb 10-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   36.883934] usb 10-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   36.991964] usb usb10-port2: attempt power cycle
[   37.687937] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ohci-pci
[   38.103933] usb 10-2: device not accepting address 12, error -32
```

Exhibit B, from having put a webcam on the front USB 3.0 ports:

```
[ 1511.259179] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command
[ 1511.259207] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[ 1511.259215] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[ 1511.259222] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1511.259253] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to set UVC probe control : -110 (exp. 26).
[ 1511.259267] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -19 (exp. 26).
[ 1511.259270] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
```

Exhibit C, from putting an external HD on the back USB 2.0 ports after about 10 minutes of boot:

```
[ 1650.811952] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 1650.955963] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1651.195949] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1651.439960] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1651.587956] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1651.827958] usb 1-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1651.939968] usb usb1-port5: attempt power cycle
[ 1652.147951] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 1652.579970] usb 1-5: device not accepting address 9, error -32
[ 1652.711972] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[ 1653.147958] usb 1-5: device not accepting address 10, error -32
[ 1653.147991] usb usb1-port5: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 1653.539962] usb 10-5: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ohci-pci
[ 1653.703976] usb 10-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1653.979972] usb 10-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1654.247971] usb 10-5: new full-speed USB device number 15 using ohci-pci
[ 1654.411987] usb 10-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1654.679963] usb 10-5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1654.788026] usb usb10-port5: attempt power cycle
[ 1655.031984] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
```

Exhibit D, from putting a keyboard on the motherboard's USB 1.0 port meant for flashing a new BIOS into the motherboard:

```
[ 1753.111289] usb 5-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1759.488568] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[ 1759.676571] usb 10-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1759.944563] usb 10-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1760.236572] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[ 1760.404559] usb 10-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1760.696573] usb 10-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1760.804598] usb usb10-port2: attempt power cycle
[ 1761.504564] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 28 using ohci-pci
[ 1761.924566] usb 10-2: device not accepting address 28, error -32
[ 1762.108584] usb 10-2: new full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[ 1762.528566] usb 10-2: device not accepting address 29, error -32
[ 1762.528604] usb usb10-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 1773.480652] usb 11-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-pci
[ 1773.672634] usb 11-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1773.944638] usb 11-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 1774.236652] usb 11-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci-pci
```